# Generic type guards assuming never

Tags: typescript, generics

This code:

```
class X<T> {
  isString(): this is X<string> {
    return true;
  }

  isNumber(): this is X<number> {
    return false;
  }
}

const x = new X();

if (x.isString()) {

} else if (x.isNumber()) { // Line 15

}
```

Which I think that semantically is correct, generates this error:

> message: 'Property 'isNumber' does not exist on type 'never'.'
>   at: '15,14'

Why? How should I write the `if` batch of sentences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Types in typescript are structural.

In your example, `X<string>` and `X<number>` are structurally identical - they both have two type guard methods, `isString()` and `isNumber()`, and nothing else. So the compiler assumes that if the first typeguard returns true, the second must also return true (because in reality they are testing for the same type), and `else` branch is unreachable.

As soon as you make `X` to actually depend on `T`, it compiles:

```
class X<T> {
  t: T;

  isString(): this is X<string> {
    return true;
  }

  isNumber(): this is X<number> {
    return false;
  }
}

const x = new X();

if (x.isString()) {

} else if (x.isNumber()) { // Line 15

}
```